# Use 'find' command to search for PNG files, pipe output to imagemagick for batch conversion

Tags: linux, find, pipe, imagemagick

I've got a directory with thousands of image files, mostly JPG but some PNG.  The files have no extension, they're just numbered.  I need to convert all of them to JPG.

Using *find* I can get a list of all the files with their types, and from that I can use Imagemagick to convert from PNG to JPG by specifying their type:

```
convert png:10020 jpg:10020.jpg
```

But I'd like to do this as a batch across all the files.  How can I pipe the output of *find* and convert all the PNG files to JPG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type f | while read IN; do
  if [ "x$(file -b --mime-type $IN)" = "ximage/png" ]; then
    convert png:$IN jpg:$IN.jpg;
  fi;
done;
```

Meaning of arguments:

1. `.`
   Find in the current directory
2. `-type f`
   Just find files, not directories/sockets/etc.
3. `while read IN; do`
   Put each filename into the variable `IN` and run the loop on it.
4. `if [ "x$(file -b --mime-type $IN)" = "ximage/png" ]; then`
   Check if the file is a PNG...
5. `convert png:$IN jpg:$IN.jpg;`
   ...and if it is, convert it.
6. `fi; done;`
   We are done!

I have tested it this time, and it works, converting a directory full of PNG's without the `.png` extension to JPG's.

Comment: I also suggest you use the `-iname` (ignore case) option in the case it's `.PNG` and not `.png` or even `.PnG` etc.

Comment: @arielnmz It seems that you are more familiar with `find` than I am. At the time you left the comment, my command wouldn't even run...I have it working now, though.

Comment: That would be fine IF the files had extensions, but they don't.  That's why the question was asking about using the file command to get the actual filetype, then to convert only those PNG images that are found.

Comment: @Hibiscus OK, I will update my answer to reflect that. It will be hard, but not impossible. :)

Comment: @Hibiscus The latest edit works for me. Try it and see if it works for you!

Comment: That's exactly what I need!  Thanks!  One question: all this make sense to me, and your explanation helps a lot.